# How do I use enter to edit a String resource in XML(Android) without the enter actually becoming a part of the String?

Tags: android, xml, string, formatting

I have a String resource in an XML file on my Android project. It's a paragraph, so in the interest of formatting it so I can see the entire thing on my screen, I put an return every 10 words or so. Unfortunately, when I run my project, the string reads my returns as a part of the text and thus, my String appears as a choppy block. Is there a way for me to use the Enter key solely for editing purposes and not have it affect the actual String?